# Export query results from BigQuery to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I am trying to export the results of a query in BigQuery, and get the data into Postgres. The data may be as much 250 million record, ~26Gb.

Option 1:

Save query results to a temp table
Export table to csv(s)
Bulk upsert to postgres

(This will be slow)

Option 2:

Somehow get the two DBs to speak directly
I don't know if this is possible

Thank you for any information!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [BigQuery Foreign Data Wrapper for postgreSQL](https://github.com/gabfl/bigquery_fdw) allows you to query BigQuery directly from within PostgreSQL. Using this and a [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html) statement should allow you to efficiently and directly copy from BigQuery to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I will mark this as the answer when I get it working.

Comment: This might work for queries that reduce data from the original 26GB to an understandable result - but for 26GB of data I'll recommend to export to CSV and re-import.