# How do I efficiently migrate the BigQuery Tables to On-Prem Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I need to migrate the tables from the BigQuery to the on-prem Postgres database.

How can I efficiently achieve that?

Some thoughts that are coming

1. I will use Google APIs to export the data from the tables
2. Store it locally
3. And finally, import to Postgres

But I am not sure if that can be done for a huge amount of data in TBs. Also, how can I automate this process? Can I use Jenkins for that?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the data from BigQuery, store it and importing it to PostgreSQL is a good approach. Here are other two alternatives that you can consider:

1) There's a [PostgreSQL wrapper for BigQuery](https://github.com/gabfl/bigquery_fdw) that allows to query directly from BigQuery. Depending on your case scenario this might be the easiest way to transfer the data; although, for TBs it might not be the best approach. This suggestion was made by @David in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745594/export-query-results-from-bigquery-to-postgres).

2) Using [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/). You can create a ETL process using Apache Beam to made the transfer. Take a look at this how-to for [transferring data from BigQuery to CloudSQL](https://datascience.com.co/how-to-transfer-bigquery-table-to-cloud-sql-using-cloud-dataflow-849de7bd6053). You would need to adapt it for local PostgreSQL, but the idea maintains.

Here's another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53121698/7517757) that gives more context on this approach.